# Array element to struct constrained method

Tags: c#

I need to pass value from array to method that has where T : struct generic constraint.

I have `object[] values;` That for example contains `{ (int)7, (byte)3, (char)'a' }` (i don't know structure at compile time)

and i need to pass that array, or all elements one by one to any of following methods

```
DataStream(Array array)
DataStream(IntPtr ptrToArray, int sizeInbytes)

DataStream.Write<T>(T value) where T : struct
DataStream.WriteBytes(byte[] bytes)
```

First method will write some error in GCHandle.Alloc (that object does not contain primitive data)
Third mthod will not compile since object is not struct

*Actual problem is that i am trying to create MeshBuilder in SlimDX that will contain VertexChannels and then build VertexBuffer out of them*

Comment: So what's the question?  Those signatures are not working?  What do you expect us to do about it?  Either way, we'll need to see what sort of operations you intend to do or how you call them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, your array will contain *boxed* values which is why the first two will fail. You're not going to be able to do this all in one call.

Options:

- Call the generic `Write` method using reflection, picking up the execution-time type of the values that way:

  ```
  // You may well need to do more work here, if DataStream.Write is
  // overloaded.
  MethodInfo genericMethod = typeof(DataStream).GetMethod("Write");
  foreach (object value in values)
  {
      Type type = value.GetType();
      MethodInfo method = genericMethod.MakeGenericMethod(type);
      method.Invoke(dataStream, value);
  }
  ```
- Use dynamic typing if you're using C# 4 and .NET 4:

  ```
  foreach (dynamic value in values)
  {
      dataStream.Write(value);
  }
  ```
- Explicitly check each value against your supported types:

  ```
  foreach (object value in values)
  {
      if (value is char)
      { 
          dataStream.Write((char) value);
      }
      else if (value is byte)
      {
          dataStream.Write((byte) value);
      }
      else if (value is int)
      {
          dataStream.Write((int) value);
      }
      else
      {
          throw new ArgumentException("Unsupported type in input data");
      }
  }
  ```

All of these are likely to be fairly slow, to be honest. The first is likely to be the slowest, but I wouldn't like to bet on anything without testing it first.

Comment: Yeah i know reason of why they fail. And i can't actually use GetType, since data can bbe almost anything that is struct. Since it is for constructing vertex buffer with a lot of vertices, i also don't want to use reflection that much :) But dynamic is great, thanks!

Comment: Hm visual studio (or resharper) writes error when i try use dynamic in method with struct constraint (but everything will compile and run ok)

Comment: @Kikaimaru: Dynamic is effectively using reflection behind the scenes too. If this is a performance-critical method, you're going to have trouble either way, to be honest.